# Advanced search link in second line of bootstrap 3.0 navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3.0, and I need to place second line (link to advanced search) under text input.

Now I have:
[image: a busy cat]

I want: 
[image: a busy cat]

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Just standard Bootstrap navbar with search http://jsbin.com/onAFANO/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decrease the height of the search form input and button using `input-sm` and `btn-sm`, and then customize `navbar-form`..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><b><i class="icon-thumbs-up-alt icon-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Baza Dobrych Praktyk</b></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Logowanie</a> <a class="btn navbar-btn  btn-default">Rejestracja</a> 
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left pull-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="tytul dobrej praktyki">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">szukaj</button>
              <div><a href=""><small>advanced</small></a></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS..

```
.navbar-form {margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0;line-height:10px;}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/89042